# Can someone please tell me why the following Java code (for comparing two linked lists) is giving NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Can someone please tell me why the following Java code (for comparing two linked lists) is giving NullPointerException? This was in HackerRank.

```
int CompareLists(Node headA, Node headB) {
    // This is a "method-only" submission. 
    // You only need to complete this method 
    int i = 1;
    Node tempA = new Node();
    Node tempB = new Node();

    tempA = headA;
    tempB = headB;
    if(tempA == null || tempB == null){
        return 0;
    }
        while(i==1){
            if(tempA.data==tempB.data){
                i=1;
                }
            else if(tempA == null && tempB == null)
                return i;
            else{
                i=0;                    
            }

            tempA = tempA.next;
            tempB = tempB.next;                
        }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Improve your question, providing at least the stacktrace 1 - Where is the exception thrown exactly 2 - You are not checking if data is not null 3 - You are not checking if tempA and tempB are null after doing `next`

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?  Which object is `null`?  Stack Overflow is a poor substitute for a debugger.

Comment: 1. As hackerrank is testing this code, nullpointerexception is shown as being thrown at some lines beyond these lines.
2. How to check if data is null. int-type and data-type comparison? How?
3. After doing tempA and tempB as next, the loop will run again and if null, will be taken care of by the else{ i=0;} at which loop will break. Am I wrong?

Comment: Consider paying attention to details.  Detail 1: tempA = new Node();  Detail 2: tempA.next is not set.  Detail 3: tempA = tempA.next;  Detail 4: tempA.data is a null pointer reference.

Comment: 2. If data is an int, then there is no need for checking if they are null. 3 You are doing `tempA = tempA.next; tempB = tempB.next;` , and then, the first thing you do in the loop is `if(tempA.data .. ` . tempA might be null at that point

Comment: Oh yes. I got it. Now no more NPE even though the code is still not giving correct results. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `tempA.next` or `tempB.next` are null and you attempt to access `.data` it will throw an NPE. You need to have your `else if(tempA == null && tempB ==null)` as the initial if statement before attempting to access `.data`.

Comment: Oh yes. Now I understand. Thanks. It is still giving erroneous results but no more NPEs.